# Fetching multiple data from different axios API with react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, axios

I'm new with react+redux.
I need to fetch data from two different API using axios in the same react component.
The data displays for me but not together every time I refresh the page only one of the data displays.

**Here is my component :**

```
const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
        "& .MuiTableCell-head": {
            fontSize: "1.5rem",
            padding: theme.spacing(0.1)

        }
    },
    paper: {
        margin: theme.spacing(2),
        padding: theme.spacing(2)
    },
    newButton: {
        position: 'absolute'

    }
})
const Workflow = ({classes, ...props}) => {

    const validate = () =>{
    }

    //Toast
 const {addToast} = useToasts()


 const [currentId, setCurrentId] = useState(0)


const initialFieldValues = {
    idworkflow : '',
    workflow_title : '',
    iddocument : ''
}


useEffect(() => {
    props.fetchAllWorkflows()
    props.fetchAllDocuments()
    console.log(props)
}, [])


  
const {
    values,
    setErrors
} = useForm(initialFieldValues, validate, props.setCurrentId)


    return (
        <div>


            <Paper className={classes.paper} elevation={6}>
                <Grid container>
<Grid item xs={12}>
                        <TableContainer>
                            <Table aria-label='sticky table'>
                                <TableHead className={classes.root}>
                                    <TableRow>
                                        <TableCell><h6><i><p>Workflow Title</p></i></h6></TableCell>
                                        <TableCell><h6><i><p>Document</p></i></h6></TableCell>
                                 </TableRow>
                                </TableHead>
                                <TableBody>
                                    {props.workflowList
                                        .map((record) => {
                                            return (<TableRow  hover>
                                                <TableCell>{record.workflowTitle}</TableCell>
                                                {props.documentList.map((records)=>{
                                                    if (record.iddocument === records.iddocument)
                                                     return( <TableCell>{records.title}</TableCell>)
                                                })}

                                             </TableRow>)
                                        })
                                    }

                                </TableBody>
                            </Table>
                           
                        </TableContainer>
                    </Grid>


                </Grid>

            </Paper>

        </div>

    );
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    workflowList: state.WorkflowReducer.list,
    documentList : state.DocumentReducer.list,
})

const mapActionToProps = {
fetchAllWorkflows : actions.fetchAll,
fetchAllDocuments : Dactions.fetchAll,

}
 
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapActionToProps)(withStyles(styles)(Workflow));
```

**Here is the action:**

```
import api from "./api";

    export const ACTION_TYPES = {
        CREATE:'CREATE',
        UPDATE:'UPDATE', 
        DELETE:'DELETE',
        FETCH_ALL:'FETCH_ALL',
        FETCH_BY_DOMAIN:'FETCH_BY_DOMAIN'
    }
    
    const formateData = data => ({
        ...data
    })
    
    export const fetchAll  = () => dispatch =>{
        api.dDocument().fetchAll()
        .then(Response => {
            
            dispatch({
             type : ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL,
             payload :Response.data
         })
    
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
         
    }
    
    
    export const fetchByDomain  = (id) => dispatch =>{
        
        api.dDocument().fetchByDomain(id)
        .then(Response=> {
            
            dispatch({
             type : ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_BY_DOMAIN,
             payload : Response.data
         })
          console.log(Response)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
         
    }
    export const create = (data, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
        data = formateData(data)
        api.dDocument().create(data)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: ACTION_TYPES.CREATE,
                    payload: res.data
                })
                onSuccess()
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    
    export const update = (id, data, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
        data = formateData(data)
       
        api.dDocument().update(id, data)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE,
                    payload: { id, ...data }
                })
                onSuccess()
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
    
    export const Delete = (id, onSuccess) => dispatch => {
        api.dDocument().delete(id)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: ACTION_TYPES.DELETE,
                    payload: id
                })
                onSuccess()
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }
```

**Here is the reducer:**

```
import { ACTION_TYPES } from "../actions/dDomain";

const initialState = {
    list:[]
}

export const DomainReducer = (state = initialState,action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL:
            
            return {
                ...state,
                list : [...action.payload]
            }

        
            

        case ACTION_TYPES.CREATE:
            
            return {
                    ...state,
                    list : [...state.list, action.payload]
                }    
        case ACTION_TYPES.UPDATE:
            
                    return {
                        
                            ...state,
                
                            list : state.list.map(x=>x.iddomain == action.payload.id ? action.payload:x)
                        }    

        case ACTION_TYPES.DELETE:
            
                            return {
                                    ...state,
                                    list : state.list.filter(x=>x.iddomain != action.payload )
                                }    
        default:
            return state
    }

}
```

**Here is the API management file:**

```
import axios from "axios";
import { store } from "./store";


const baseUrl = "http://localhost:60227/api/"



export default {


    dDomain(url = baseUrl + 'Domain/') {
        let localtoken = localStorage.token
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            //fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url + id, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } })
        }
    },

    dRole(url = baseUrl + 'Rolelist/') {
        let localtoken = localStorage.token
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            //fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url + id, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } })
        }
    },

    dAuthentication(url = baseUrl + 'Authentication/Register/') {
        return {
            register: newRecord => axios.post('http://localhost:60227/api/Authentication/Register/', newRecord),

            login: newRecord => axios.post('http://localhost:60227/api/Authentication/login/', newRecord)

        }
    },

    dRoleUser(url = baseUrl + 'Domain/') {
        return {

            fetchAll: () => axios.get('http://localhost:60227/api/Ruserrole/GetRuserrole/'),

            create: newRecord => axios.post('http://localhost:60227/api/Ruserrole/AddRUserRole', newRecord),

        }
    },

    dDocument(url = baseUrl + 'Document/') {
        let localtoken = localStorage.token
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            fetchByDomain: (id)=> axios.get(url + id, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            //fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url + id, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } })
        }
    },

    dWorkflow(url = baseUrl + 'Workflow/') {
        let localtoken = localStorage.token
        return {
            fetchAll: () => axios.get(url, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            //fetchById: id => axios.get(url + id),
            create: newRecord => axios.post(url, newRecord, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            update: (id, updateRecord) => axios.put(url + id, updateRecord, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } }),
            delete: id => axios.delete(url + id, { headers: { "Authorization": `Bearer ${localtoken}` } })
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: is `ACTION_TYPES.FETCH_ALL` for `dDomain` and `dRole` a different string or the same string?

Comment: Different strings , two different URL used by axios.get

Comment: But your url is not included in `CREATE:'CREATE'`. If the other API also uses the string `'CREATE'` those two will override each other. Each action is always sent to each reducer.

Comment: I figure out what you mean , Thank you for offering your valuable advice.,it helped me well , thank you so much man

Comment: For what it's worth you are probably following an outdated tutorial and modern redux doesn't really require you to use things like string action types at all any more. I can really recommend you take a look at the official Redux tutorials as that will make your life a lot easier: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Comment: Well noted , appreciate your advice , thanks again